# Uploading files to a webserver java FileUpload

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

I'm using apache's `FileUpload` in order to upload some files to my webserver. Problem is I don't want to upload them to a specific location on the machine i.e : `c:\tmp`, but rather to a relative path such as `/ProjectName/tmp/`

Here's my code:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String TMP_DIR_PATH = "c:\\tmp";
private File tmpDir;
private static final String DESTINATION_DIR_PATH ="/files";
private File destinationDir;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    tmpDir = new File(TMP_DIR_PATH);
    if(!tmpDir.isDirectory()) {
        throw new ServletException(TMP_DIR_PATH + " is not a directory");
    }
    String realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(DESTINATION_DIR_PATH);
    destinationDir = new File(realPath);
    if(!destinationDir.isDirectory()) {
        throw new ServletException(DESTINATION_DIR_PATH+" is not a directory");
    }
}
```

I want to change `TMP_DIR_PATH` so it's relative to my project, help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you aware that this way all uploaded files will get lost whenever you redeploy the project or even when you just restart the server? Is that covered by the business requirement? No? Then you should be storing them in an absolute path outside the webapp.

Comment: I'm aware of that, it's just a little project I have to present, nothing more than that.

Comment: OK, cheers, go ahead with `ServletContext#getRealPath()`. Be careful that you deploy this into a container which is configured to expand the WAR, otherwise `getRealPath()` would only return `null`.

Comment: Aw, how can I cope with it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your *actual* concern is the hardcoding of the `c:\\tmp` part which makes the code unportable, then consider using [`File#createTempFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead. This will create the file in the platform default temp location as specified by the `java.io.tmpdir` system property.

```
File file = File.createTempFile("upload", ".tmp");
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
// ...
```

Comment: Hey, is there a way I can upload them to WEB-INF instead of those temp repositories?

Comment: Not if the container doesn't expand the WAR. There's then namely no means of a physical local disk file system folder, but just some space in the server memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the temp directory to be relative to your project you'll have to use `getRealPath` and then make sure you create the directory if it doesn't already exist.

You can also use `File dir = (File) getServletContext().getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");` to fetch an app-specific temp directory provided by the container.